# ¿Como saltar de registros mysql usando bucle en php, y de cada registro iterado hacer un calculo entre valores de campos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Lo que hace este código es recibir en una variable el número de clases impartidas, en un `array` el número de inasistencias de cada alumno, en otro ´array´ el idGrupo, que siempre es el mismo, y en otro `array` recibe el idAlumno, estos datos son mandados desde una tabla como formulario.
Lo que intentaba hacer es que en base a núm. de sesiones y asistencias mediante una regla de 3 calcular el porcentaje de asistencia obtenido de cada alumno.
Esta parte parece funcionar bien, pero aparte tiene que calcular el promedio de 3 calificaciones de cada alumno, estas calificaciones son recuperadas de la base de datos, se debe evaluar si el porcentaje de asistencia de cada alumno es mayor o igual a 80, guardar en el registro correspondiente el promedio obtenido anteriormente, de ser menor a 80 debe tener una calificación reprobatoria = 5.

Lo que logró hacer bien es el salto de registro en registro, para hacer esos cálculos en cada uno de ellos. Lo estaba intentado hacer inicializando una variable con el primer `idAlumno` encontrado y de ahí compararlo en el bucle si es el mismo del recuperado por otra variable. Es más un error de lógica.

```js
//CALCULO DE PROMEDIOS DE ALUMNO Y % DE ASISTENCIAS
 
  elseif( (isset($_POST['numsesiones']) ) && (!empty($_POST['asistotales'])) ) {
    $grupo4      = $_POST['idgpo']; //arreglo idgrupo[] siempre es el mismo
    $gpo4 = $grupo4[0]; //el idGrupo es el mismo en todo el arreglo
    $alumno4     = $_POST['idalumno']; //arreglo idalumno[]

     $consulta1 = "SELECT A.matricula, A.nombre, AG.parcial1, AG.parcial2, AG.parcial3, AG.final, AG.idAlumno, AG.idGrupo FROM alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, materias M, periodos Pr, profesores P, grupos G WHERE M.idMateria = G.materia and A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and G.profesor = P.idProfesor and G.periodo = Pr.idPeriodo and AG.idGrupo = $gpo4 ORDER BY A.nombre";

     $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta1);
     $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta1);

     $fila = $res->fetch_assoc(); //array asociativo para obtener el primer registro de alumno
     $fila2 = $res2->fetch_assoc(); //array asociativo para obtener los demas registros
  
     $nalumno = count($alumno4); //cuenta los elementos del arreglo de los id alumno[]

      $asistenciasalumno  = $_POST['asistotales']; //valores de arreglo recibido
      $numsesiones  = $_POST['numsesiones'];  //1 valor recibido de un input
      $bandera = $fila['idAlumno'];  //asignamos a variable el primer registro de alumno encontrado

       for ($a = 0; $a < $nalumno; $a++) {  //for recorre elementos del array[] idAlumno

            $alum = $alumno4[$a]; //variable toma valor del arreglo en el id
            $gpos = $grupo4[$a]; //variable toma el valor del arreglo de idgrupo, (siempre es el mismo)

            //asignanle a variable el indice del arreglo
            $asis = $asistenciasalumno[$a];

            $regla = $asis * 100;
            $asis = $regla/$numsesiones;  //regla de 3 para sacr porcentaje de asistencia, 
            $asis = round($asis);
            echo $asis; //prueba
            echo "<br>"; //prueba

            $sqlp = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET asistencias = '{$asis}'
                  WHERE idAlumno = '{$alum}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpos}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

          while ($fila2 = $res2->fetch_assoc()) {

            if($bandera == $fila2['idAlumno']) { //si la bandera es igual al primer idAlumno
            //obteniendo las calificaciones de los 3 parciales por alumno
            $p1b = $fila2['parcial1'];
            $p2b = $fila2['parcial2'];
            $p3b = $fila2['parcial3'];
        
            $suma = $p1b+$p2b+$p3b;
            $promedio = $suma/3;  
            } else {
          
            $p1b = $fila2['parcial1'];
            $p2b = $fila2['parcial2'];
            $p3b = $fila2['parcial3'];
        
            $suma = $p1b+$p2b+$p3b;
            $promedio = $suma/3;  
            }
            $bandera = $fila['idAlumno'];
          }
             if ($asis >= 80) {           //DE SER MENOR EL % DE ASSITENCIAS OBTENIDO DEL 80
                  $sqlb = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = '{$promedio}'
                  WHERE idAlumno = '{$alum}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpos}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
             } elseif ($asis < 80) {  
                  $sqlb = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = 5
                  WHERE idAlumno = '{$alum}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpos}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
             } 
             } //for recorre                          
      } //if empty numsesiones && isset asistotales/
```

Comment: Hola, desconozco que tantos usuarios tenga este sistema pero queria avisarte que es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL, si no estas muy al tanto del tema podria proveerte algunos documentos para interiorizarte.

Comment: es cierto, si estaría bien gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplifique un poco tu codigo para facilitar la compresion. Uno de los problemas que tenias era que estabas recorriendo un array de claves incremetales usando un FOR de forma incorrecta creo que fue a raiz de esto que complicaste por demas la logica guardando un flag con el id del alumno que estabas recorriendo.

Te dejo el codigo arreglado y mas abajo te explico.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['numsesiones']) && !empty($_POST['asistotales'])) {
    $id_grupo = $_POST['idgpo'][0]; // Valor fijo, es siempre igual
    $alumnos = $_POST['idalumno']; // Array de idalumno[]
    $asistencias  = $_POST['asistotales']; //valores de arreglo recibido
    $numsesiones  = $_POST['numsesiones'];  //1 valor recibido de un input
    $sql = "SELECT A.matricula, A.nombre, AG.parcial1, AG.parcial2, AG.parcial3, AG.final, AG.idAlumno, AG.idGrupo FROM alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, materias M, periodos Pr, profesores P, grupos G WHERE M.idMateria = G.materia and A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and G.profesor = P.idProfesor and G.periodo = Pr.idPeriodo and AG.idGrupo = $gpo4 ORDER BY A.nombre";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    for ($a = 0; $a < count($alumnos); $a++) {  //for recorre elementos del array[] idAlumno

        $id_alumno = $alumnos[$a];

        //asignanle a variable el indice del arreglo
        $alumno_asistencias = $asistencias[$a];

        //Promedio de asistencias
        $alumno_asistencias_promedio = round(($alumno_asistencias * 100) / $numsesiones);

        echo $alumno_asistencias_promedio; //prueba
        echo "<br>"; //prueba

        //Update
        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET asistencias = '{$alumno_asistencias_promedio}' WHERE idAlumno = '{$id_alumno}' AND idGrupo = '{$id_grupo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            $promedio = ($row['parcial1'] + $row['parcial2'] + $row['parcial3'])/3;

            if ($alumno_asistencias_promedio >= 80){
                $sqlb = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = '{$alumno_asistencias_promedio}' WHERE idAlumno = '{$id_alumno}' AND idGrupo = '{$id_grupo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
            }else{
                $sqlb = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = 5 WHERE idAlumno = '{$id_alumno}' AND idGrupo = '{$id_grupo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

La verdad solo correji el codigo usando sentido comun pero no termino de entender los valores que estas recibiendo, en caso de que no te funcione podrias añadir a tu pregunta un print_r / var_dump de todo lo que estas recibiendo por POST?.

Comment: si, es cierto tiene razón, esta más entendible así.muchas gracias, saludos....

Comment: una pregunta, y por que? el: $a < count($alumnos)-1  (-1)

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, tenes razon, esta resta solo aplicaria cuando en tu FOR esperas que $a sea menor o igual que la cantidad de valores del array, pero como solo verificas que sea menor no aplica.

Comment: De acuerdo gracias, saludos

Comment: Si la respuesta a esta u otras preguntas te sirvio, por favor, considera calificarla positivamente.